# difference between mysqli_query and mysqli_real_query

Tags: php, mysqli

What is the difference between `mysqli::query` and `mysqli::real_query`?

OR

What is the difference between `mysqli_query` and `mysqli_real_query`?

Comment: Not sure why this question was closed. It probably *should* be answered by the manual, but it's not very clear there, and the text of the "not constructive" close reason doesn't seem to fit it at all.

Comment: Yeah, this should definitely not be closed and especially for the reasons listed to close this. I just came here for this exact question and glad I'm did. Moderators need to seriously stop being so click happy when they see a "Close" link on a post.

Comment: @SazzadHossainKhan I already did, but apparently was outvoted 3 to 2 when it was reviewed by other users ([there's a report here, but you can probably only see it with a high-rep account](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/5560191)). I don't think The Duke of Marshall has the reputation to cast such a vote.

Comment: I also request that this question be re-opened.  I believe the question is perfectly valid, and well formed.  I viewed the PHP manual before coming here, and was also stymied by the explanation.  Now I understand that, in the (undocumented) code I was reviewing, the error check on the _$mySQLi->real_query()_ function tests for a failed SQL command, while the error check on the **separate** _$mySQLi->store_result()_ function tests for a non-null result set.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Look at the documentation of [mysqli_query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)():

> Functionally, using this function is identical to calling
> mysqli_real_query() followed either by mysqli_use_result() or
> mysqli_store_result().

From what I understand real_query actually executes the query, and use/store_result initiates the process of retrieving a result set for the query.
query() does both.

Comment: The documentation is different now: "**For non-DML queries** (not INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE), this function is **similar** to calling mysqli_real_query() followed by either mysqli_use_result() or mysqli_store_result()."

Answer (score 20):

`mysqli::query` will return a result if there is any.

`mysql::real_query` will return true on success or false if not

You could have seen this in the php doc:

- [query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php),
- [real_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php).

Comment: help me writing better answers by describing me why you downvoted it

Answer (score 5):

Bit late, but the biggest advance for me is the RAM usage when these functions are called with default settings: with `mysqli_real_query()` you do not copy the whole result into the RAM, which `mysqli_query()` by default does (although it can be changed by using the `$resultmode` parameter).

Comment: you can have the same with mysqli_query(), just tell it to make an unbuffered call

Answer (score 3):

In practice there is another difference I don't see in other answers. **You could need to use `mysqli_real_query()` for a `CALL` statement**.

If you are calling a stored procedure, then it can return more than one result. `mysqli_query()` will fetch the first result, but could be more results that needs to be fetched, and that would cause an error. You need to use `mysqli_real_query`(or `mysqli_multi_query()`) to fetch those result sets.

Sadly that explanation is in the [stored procedures section of the PHP docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.stored-procedures.php), so is hard to reach.

I let you a code example, just in case, calling a procedure that suppose to return several result sets using `mysqli::real_query`:

```
$query="CALL storedProcedure()";
if($conn->real_query($query)){              
    do{
        if($result=$conn->store_result()) {
            while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
                print_r($row);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
    }while($conn->more_results() && $conn->next_result());          
}
```

Comment: you can do that with mysqli_query() query as well. check your premises

Comment: @YourCommonSense Manual says explicity: "Result sets returned from a stored procedure **cannot be fetched correctly using mysqli_query()**. The mysqli_query() function combines statement execution and fetching the first result set into a buffered result set, if any. However, there are additional stored procedure result sets hidden from the user which cause mysqli_query() to fail returning the user expected result sets."

Comment: Well, the manual is wrong. Just call the usual routine with next_result() and store_result() and get those additional result sets as well

Comment: @YourCommonSense I learned it the hard way years ago, and had to change my code, but maybe new versions of PHP allow it. Sounds rare the Manual is wrong, but is not impossible. Will try it if I can, meawhile seems fair to give an advice extracted from the official documentation.

Comment: That's only a minor algorithmical inconvenience, not a some inherent feature. you just don't call store_result() on the first pass, that's all. in your loop you can just move it in the while clause and then you can change real_query to query() without any problem.basically, which function you are using is not related to stored procedures.