# mysqli::$field_count vs mysqli_result::$field_count

Tags: php, mysqli

I was looking in the php manual and found two functions that look very similar to me:

```
mysqli_result::$field_count or mysqli_num_fields
```

and

```
mysqli::$field_count or mysqli_field_count()
```

Do they differ in any way?

Comment: I had already read the documentation but couldn't find any differences

Comment: Apparently there's also a difference between [`mysqli::query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) and [`mysqli::real_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-query.php), which may be relevant, but the manual is oddly silent on what is actually "real" about `real_query`

Comment: @IMSoP, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13469713/1232526

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this may help:

```
Object oriented style
int mysqli->field_count ;

Procedural style
int mysqli_field_count(mysqli link);

Returns the number of columns for the most recent query on the connection represented by the link parameter. This function can be useful when using the mysqli_store_result function to determine if the query should have produced a non-empty result set or not without knowing the nature of the query.
```

for more detail visit here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.field-count.html

```
Object oriented style
int mysqli_result->field_count ;

Procedural style
int mysqli_num_fields(mysqli_result result);
Returns the number of fields from specified result set.
```

for more detail visit here:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli-result.field-count.html

you can see in both the cases one receives a input but the other does not

Comment: thanks I would upvote your answer if I had enough reputation (It's my first question)  
I see that mysqli->field_count does not require having to know the type of the query

Answer (score 2):

Those two functions accept different parameters:

- `mysqli_num_fields()` accepts a `$con` variable - the mysql connection variable - and returns the number of rows for the latest query preformed using this connection.
- `mysqli_field_count()' accepts a`$result` variable - the result set of any previous query - and returns its number of returned row.

You could presumably use `mysqli_field_count()` for your latest query, but you could never use `mysqli_num_fields()` for any query but your most recent one.

Comment: But I guess the question is, why did the designers of mysqli feel the need to include `mysqli_num_fields`? What is its advantage over querying a particular result set?

Comment: I think that `mysqli_num_fields()` result is already in memory, cached per connection, so it should be faster compared to `mysqli_field_count()`.

Comment: This seems like a valid hypothesis.