# PHP : Continue get me out

Tags: php, continue

Why my second if is never executed ? It seems like the continue sentence get me out of the foreach. I have tried the elseif without success.

```
        foreach($columns as $i=>$column) 
        {
            // Check if column exists
            $sql = "SELECT '$column' FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$database' AND TABLE_NAME = '$strTable'";
            if(mysqli_real_query($link, $sql)) 
            {
                echo 'Column '.$column.' was created! <br>';
                continue; 
            }
            $sql = "alter table '$strTable' add column '$column' varchar (30)"; 
            if(mysqli_real_query($link, $sql)) 
            {
                echo 'Column '.$column.' was created! <br>';
            }
            $cols .= $column.','; 
        }
```

Comment: `continue` means to start the next iteration of the loop, skipping the rest of the body.

Comment: Simply remove the `continue`.

Comment: the purpose is to NOT add a column that already exists.

Answer (score 1):

You're not testing whether the query found any rows. `mysqli_real_query()` is successful as long as it didn't get an error, but that doesn't mean the query matched anything. You need to get the result of the query.

Also, you're just checking whether the table exists, not whether that column exists in the table.

`continue` skips the entire rest of the loop body. You should use `else` to execute the second block when the column isn't found.

Use `mysqli_query()` if you want to use the result. Otherwise, you need to call `mysqli_use_result()` and `mysqli_store_result()` first; see [difference between mysqli_query and mysqli_real_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469653/difference-between-mysqli-query-and-mysqli-real-query)

```
foreach($columns as $column) 
{
    // Check if column exists
    $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$database' AND TABLE_NAME = '$strTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = '$column'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
    {
        echo 'Column '.$column.' already exists! <br>';
    } else {
        $sql = "alter table '$strTable' add column '$column' varchar (30)"; 
        if(mysqli_real_query($link, $sql)) 
        {
            echo 'Column '.$column.' was created! <br>';
        }
    }
    $cols .= $column.','; 
}
```

Comment: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given

Comment: $sql = "SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$database' AND TABLE_NAME = '$strTable' AND **COLUMN_NAME** = '$column'";